# Can anyone share the current eth.syncing status of a sync-ed EVM node?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

For those who have a sync-ed EVM node, can help share the current eth.syncing status?

I'm still syncing my node. Below is my status.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 11365522,
  highestBlock: 11365595,
  knownStates: 526253551,
  pulledStates: 526197388,
  startingBlock: 11274865
}
```

I need to know how far is my node from fully sync-ed. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `(Etherscan)[https://etherscan.io/] latest blocks mined is in the homepage.

Comment: FYI, I'm running a fast mode GETH node. Block info already up-to-date. Account states still behind. I've tried but can't find any state info on etherscan. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `knownStates` for October was somewhere around 700 million. I suppose now it could be around 800 million for December 2020

Comment: your node will be in sync when `eth.syncing` reports `false` instead of an object of sync status

Comment: Just checked my node's status. Sync-ed 660M states so far. Will continue checking until getting false. Thanks @Nulik

Comment: @CapitalC syncing 3 million state objects per day  is too slow. My node is doing 25 million per day. You probably should increase max peers or get a better hardware (faster machine + connection)

Comment: @Nulik Would you mind sharing the GETH command line option of your node?

Comment: @CapitalC the only option I add is `--cache 24000` and `--datadir` ,not much different from yours I guess. My server is at Linode. I just recalculated the stats, I started on 18 Dec. that would be 25 days. Now I have 550 million states. So this gives me a speed of 22 million state objects (trie nodes) per day.

Comment: @CapitalC to download 800 million object I would need 36 days, I have 25 days passed, so 11 days left to download this thing

Comment: @CapitalC the final number of states is unknown, I am supposing it is 800m but it could be 900m , nobody knows

Comment: also, you need to use SSD disk . If you don't have SSD disk, you can get a USB flash 3.0 of say 64GB and use it as SSD together with `bcache` kernel module as caching device for HDD (magnetic) disk. I have been tested this setup during block import process and was getting an insertion speed of 500 million blocks per day for an archival node setup

Comment: I just synced today and it got to 700469756 knownStates first. The biggest issue was the HDD, I moved everything to a new NVMe SSD and restarted - the difference was dramatic.

Comment: My current eth.syncing status (last status before turning to FALSE):-
{
  currentBlock: 12204081,
  highestBlock: 12204082,
  knownStates: 694587350,
  pulledStates: 694587350,
  startingBlock: 12203982
}

Answer (score 0):

When you are synced, `eth.syncing` returns `false`. You will import up to the `highestBlock` and `knownStates`. Block importing will stop ~64 blocks behind head and finish importing states. Once all states are downloaded, geth will switch into a full node and sync the remaining ~64 blocks fully, as well as new ones.